# Why my Visual Code works wrong with two screens?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two screens, it means that I have laptop and one more screen which I can connect via HDMI. My Visual Code works wrong after update or due to some other problems. When I would like to open some files via Studio Code a new window opens on the second screen. BUT my second screen isn't turn on and it isn't connected via HDMI. What goes wrong??? How I can fix it? Thank you for any help :)

Comment: @JesseLi, do you see that SO has such tag? So, I'm sure that some people will help me. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the window restore windows setting to none. I think VS code is holding onto your settings on restart.

[image]

Other relevant settings to try fiddling with :

```
"window.restoreWindows": "all",
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
```